# SQL question with playing with mixed people database

Tags: sql, database

I need to write a query that returns the name of all male persons that play soccer with a female player.

The tabel is:

Persons (id, name, address, age, eyeColor, gender)

SportTogether (id, sport, personA_id, personB_id)

--The semantics of the Sport table is that personA does sport with personB.

This is which query I got till now:

```
select distinct P1.name
from Persons P1, Persons P2, SportTogether S1, SportTogether S2
where P1.id = S1.personA_id and P1.gender = 'male'
and   P2.id = S2.personB_id and P2.gender = 'female'
```

The results is two persons, which one of them is an error. I don't know how I now can get to the only one resulting person

Answer (score 0):

This query uses the table sportstogether to join person m (for male) and person f (for female) together joining on personA or personB.
As we specify the person m is male and person f is female only rows is s containing a male and a female can be used in the join. We don't need to specify that the genders are different, it is automatic.

> ```
> create table persons(id int not null primary key auto_increment,name varchar(10), gender varchar(6));
> create table sporttogether(personA_id int, personB_id int);
> insert into persons(gender,name) values
> ('male','Tom'),('male','Dick'),('male','Harry'),
> ('female','Joan'),('female','Edna'),('female','Kate');
> insert into sporttogether values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(1,6);
> ```

> ```
> select
>   m.name,
>   f.name
> from
> persons m
> join sporttogether s 
> on m.id = s.personA_id or m.id = s.personB_id 
> join persons f 
> on f.id = s.personA_id or f.id = s.personB_id 
> where m.gender = 'male'
> and f.gender = 'female';
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | name
> :---- | :---
> Harry | Joan
> Tom   | Kate
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c51d1497e38e05a89d1f05d3c5816ad9)*

Comment: I got the same results as I got

Comment: I've coded it (and removed the typos!) and it's working fine for me. See dbFiddle link.

Comment: That is weird, by me it says it runs, but the end result isn't good. It prints one two names, but one of them is wrong and needs to be deleted.

Comment: Could you have a look at the DBfiddle link and let me know what result you expect? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5c3a66f49a5b9482d6a31e71327f4587